# Pages in different languages not updating

Tags: language, helper

I have created an homepage for the 2 languages (es/en) my site is built in, however, despite the Page Information /content/ design etc being identical, the en version will simply not display the same content as the es.

Any tips as how to fix it please?

Comment: can you please explain your question in more detail so we can help you?

Comment: Thank you, I shall try.
I have 2 home pages, one in english and one is spanish, they both have the same settings and the same html.
The spanish one displays the welcome page with tex and images, the english one doesn't.

http://caliudeflandes.com/ this is the landing page in spanish - when i change it to en, the content won't load.

Comment: I think you are saying that the section with the header 'Bienvenido a Caliu de Flandes' won't load on the English version.  Is that section being included by a CMS Static Block? If so check the static block settings to see if it is set to allow display on both English and Spanish store views.

Comment: Hi there, thank you again. Yes that's it, only the english version is a separate block in english. I feel like I have tried all that, created  {{block id='Welcome'}} and inserted it in the en homepage, just won't show. I have run out of ideas :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're static block content was being rendered in the HTML but hidden via CSS.

In skin/frontend/default/mt_robel/css/styles.css line 1219 change the following style from:

```
.cms-home div.std {
    display: none;
}
```

to:

```
.cms-home div.std {
    display: block;
}
```

In the admin go to CMS -> Static Blocks - click on the static block with the ID of 'Welcome' and input your content.

If you have Magento caches enabled you may need to clear those caches for the changes to show up.